# Should "is...." be always considered as question sentence?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion

Should this always be considered as a question? or there is exception?

> In figure A: is the frame bigger then in the figure B.

Comment: Your sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question, with the punctuation "In figure A, is the frame bigger than in figure B?"

Additionally, "than" is the word you're looking for when comparing two quantities, as opposed to "then," which would be used the show something is later in time.

Comment: even if is it starting with "`is it...`" (question form) without a question mark at the end, should be considered as question sentence, always? 
O'key `then` ;) 
thank you